# How to use moment.updateLocale twice correctly?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I try to moment.updateLocale twice in different functions.

I expect the code to print

```
Today1 12:00 am
Today2 12:00 am
```

But right now it prints

```
Today at 12:00 AM
Today1 12:00 am
```

<kbd>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/culasem/8/edit?js,console)</kbd>

```
function showTime1(dateTime) {
  moment.updateLocale('en', {
    calendar : {
      sameDay : '[Today1] h:mm a'
    }
  });

  return dateTime.calendar();
}

function showTime2(dateTime) {
  moment.updateLocale('en', {
    calendar : {
      sameDay : '[Today2] h:mm a'
    }
  });

  return dateTime.calendar();
}



console.log(showTime1(moment().startOf('day')));
console.log(showTime2(moment().startOf('day')));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I should use `calendar` directly in this case. The API document is [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/).

<kbd>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/culasem/10/edit?js,console)</kbd>

```
function showTime1(dateTime) {
  return dateTime.calendar(null, {
    sameDay: '[Today1] h:mm a'
  });
}

function showTime2(dateTime) {
  return dateTime.calendar(null, {
    sameDay: '[Today2] h:mm a'
  });
}



console.log(showTime1(moment().startOf('day')));
console.log(showTime2(moment().startOf('day')));
```